# Is this a safe method of saving uploaded files?

Tags: php, security, file-upload

Is it safe enough to just check the extension of uploaded files?  If not what else should I check?

```
public function saveUploadedFile($fileInputName, $fileLocation)
    {
        $fileName=$_FILES[$fileInputName]['name'];
        if(substr($fileName,-4,4)=='.php')
        {
            my_error('have some cake');
            return FALSE;       
        }
        else 
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$fileInputName]['tmp_name'],$fileLocation.$fileName);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I usually do the opposite, check if the file is in the allowed extensions

Comment: where do I check or set allowed extensions?

Comment: what if the user uploads a perl file ?

Comment: @Matt you just have to decide which extensions should be allowed like `$allowed_extensions = array(".swf", ".gif", ".jpg");`

Comment: You can create a table in the database, or hardcode it in an array like @Teneff said

Comment: I guess it really is a simple string thing.  I was thinking it might be some kind of apache or php.ini setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check the extension, the size `filesize($filename)`; the MimeType `finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);` (if you are using > PHP 5.3; you should check if the file exists `file_exists($filename)`; I think that should do it. You should also check other extensions such as .js, .phtml and so on. Unless you want these uploaded to your server.

Good luck.

Comment: How could this be upvoted? The attacker just has to change fileLocation to overwrite anything.

Answer (score 4):

One thing I would change is your conditional here:

```
if(substr($fileName,-4,4)=='.php')
```

What you're doing is blacklisting `.php` files, which in and of itself is good.  However, (as has been pointed out in comments to the question), you should instead take an approach of whitelisting file types.  So for the conditional you would check the opposite.

Instead of logically saying "fail if the file is .php" you'd logically say something like "fail if the file is not .jpg or .gif or .doc, etc."  Having a complete list of allowed types and disallowing all others is generally safer and helps prevent people from sneaking a bad file through.

It's not a complete security solution, but in general whitelisting is safer than blacklisting.

Comment: "It's not a complete security solution": aside from checking the file extension is there someting else I should be doing?

Comment: @Matt: There's a pretty good checklist in @Teodor's answer, actually.  You can never be too careful with input checking in an application, especially a web application open to the world.

Comment: @Matt: From @Teodor's list, focus specific attention (that is, continue to do your own research) on the MimeType.  File extensions can be very easily spoofed and don't actually tell you anything about the file itself.  The MimeType from the HTTP request (and response, in the case of sending a file) is more reliable.